# The nullability property of arithmetic operators over floating point data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The MS documentation about [differences between compatibility level 80 and level 90](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb510680(v=sql.105)#remarks) is saying about compatibility level 80:

> The nullability property of arithmetic operators over floating point data type is always nullable

and for level 90:

> The nullability property of arithmetic operators over the floating point data type is changed to non-nullable for the case where the inputs are non-nullable and ANSI_WARNINGS or ARITHABORT is ON.

I don't understand it. Could you please help, thanks!

Comment: What about the statement is it you're having trouble understanding? The description is quite explicit here, so if you can let us know what parts confuse you, we can try to elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: I understand, in level 80, if value input is null, result will be null. It means, if value input is not null, result is not null. What does its difference with level 90?

Answer (score 2):

In both compatibility levels 80 and 90, the result of an arithmetic expression over floating point data types is considered nullable by default.

In compatibility level 90 - that result is considered non-nullable if (and only if) the inputs of the arithmetic expression are non-nulllable, and at least one of [`ANSI_WARNINGS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-warnings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [`ARITHABORT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-arithabort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) are set to `ON`.

Consider the following scenario:

```
declare @t as table
(
    f1 float not null,
    f2 float null
);

insert into @t (f1, f2) values (0.1, 1.0);
```

The following expression will be considered nullable in both compatibility levels:

```
select f1 * f2
from @t;
```

while the following expression will be considered nullable in compatibility level 80 but non-nullable in compatibility level 90:

```
-- in compatibility level 90 (or higher),
-- setting ansi_warnings to on implicitly sets arithabort to on.
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON; 

select f1 * f1 -- note: both inputs are non-nullable!
from @t;
```

Comment: I try it. When both input are non-nullable, result return non-nullable. It happend both level 80 and level 90

Comment: I run in SQL server 2008 R2. Does that affect the results?

Comment: There's a difference between `null` and `nullable`. The first is a value that is unknown, and therefor it can only be represented as `null`, while the second is a placeholder for a value (like a column/row combination or a variable), that can either hold a known value or `null`. The `nulllability` of the expression means that it might return a known value or `null`, it doesn't mean it must return `null`.